# Right-button drag-drop function in Gnome

Tags: mouse, gnome, drag-and-drop

While I don't really miss the annoyances that go with working on Windows, one thing I do wish I had in Gnome is the ability to hold the right-mouse button down on a file and drag it to get the context menu asking if I want to move or copy the file.

I realise the default tries to be sensible (like in Windows - defaults to move if on the same volume, or copy if on different) and that it can be overridden with `<ctrl>` or `<shift>` - but i'm still used to the right-mouse drag option and keep getting frustrated when it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag using the **middle** mouse button to obtain the desired behavior.

I don't think you can easily make it work with the right mouse button. Try looking at `gconf-editor`.

Comment: i never once thought to try the middle button - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a definite answer, but if you're using Compiz (that's the default window manager on many distros, e. g. Ubuntu), you can try out the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM). It is probably also available in the repository for your distribution. It has hundreds of options like zooming windows, automatically resizing windows to specified parts of the screen, etc. Maybe you can set the right-click behavior there. And if you can't find it there, it is well worth going through all the options, you can find some true usability highlights there.

Comment: i had a look through Compiz - doesn't seem to have the option to enable what I'm looking... thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Click both mouse buttons at the same time then drag.  It worked for me!

Comment: for most mouse interfaces - this is the same as middle button click...